# Extract number immediately after substring, ignoring spaces and non-alphanumeric

Tags: r, stringr

I've got some tweet data that looks like
text

```
WR 198  CM 23  SPIN 34

WR:22 CM:7 SPIN:0

WR 96 CM 17 SPIN 8

WR:82 CM:9 SPIN:10

WR - 206
CM - 38
SPIN - 18

WR - 140
CM - 18
Spin - 12

WR 62  CM 11  SPIN  4

WR-
CM-
Spin_

WR - 67
CM - 18
Spin - 5

WR 38 CM 2 SPIN 0
```

The tweets usually have the same sort of structure: WR/CM/SPIN (in various cases), followed by a space or non-alphanumeric character and then a number.  I'm interested in writing a function which takes as arguments the text and one of WR/CM/Spin and returns the associated number.

Here are some desired inputs and outputs for the function, `f`.

```
f("WR 198  CM 23  SPIN 34", 'WR')
198
f("WR 198  CM 23  SPIN 34", 'CM')
23
f("SPIN - 18", 'SPIN')
18
f("WR:82 CM:9 SPIN:10", "WR")
82
```

Can I achieve this with `stringr::str_extract`?  If so, what is the proper regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more sophisticated solution using just one `str_extract` statement, but you could use:

```r
library(stringr)

my_function <- function(input_string, target) {
  
  str_extract(input_string, paste0(target, "\\D*\\d+")) |> str_extract("\\d+")
  
}
```

This returns

```r
my_function("WR 198  CM 23  SPIN 34", 'WR')
#> [1] "198"
my_function("WR 198  CM 23  SPIN 34", 'CM')
#> [1] "23"
my_function("SPIN - 18", 'SPIN')
#> [1] "18"
my_function("WR:82 CM:9 SPIN:10", "WR")
#> [1] "82"
```

Comment: Nice approach of first building a fixed search pattern by including the target + any number!